# Does it have a significance that some coffee beans are shiny and others are dull?

Tags: coffee, espresso

Some espresso beans have a deep "luxurious" luster while beans from other packages seem dull. Although I have only anecdotal evidence it seems that my usual brand, [Altomayo espresso roast](https://www.altomayo.de/en/bio-espresso/92/organic-espresso-whole-beans), often has the luster while some others don't (always).

Is that from a difference in the beans, or the roasting, or is it just coincidence?

For example, my last package of [Lavazza qualita rossa](https://www.lavazza.com/en/coffee/coffee-beans/qualita-rossa-coffee-beans.html) seemed duller. I notice that the Lavazza is a mix of Arabica with Robusta while the Altomayo is pure Arabica but I think some pure Arabica also looked dull in the past. The packaging is very similar, and all samples come in kilogram airtight foil bags.

The luster clearly makes the beans look classier; is it a sign of quality?

Comment: Is there any difference in how they're packed? I'm wondering if they could rub together and roughen each other if loose in a bag on tin, while a vacuum would hold them rigidly.

Comment: @ChrisH No, all samples come in very similar bags.

Comment: Differences in the roasting/packing process could abrade the outside differently without changing the inside and therefore the overall quality - but I don't know enough to more than hint at that

Comment: This is just a guess, but it might be the oiliness of the original bean, or the amount of that that comes to the surface in a darker roast. My preferred Segafredo is a mid-dark roast with a gentle lustre. I've seen almost jet-black roasts (which I hate) that are truly shiny, & light beans such as Peaberry (obviously not for espresso) which are pale & absolutely matte-finish.

Comment: @moscafj Possibly. The beans didn't look outright oily to me. Is that the (only) reason they (can) have a luster?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica in my experience, this is how roasted coffee beans are described...shiny/oily vs. dull...along a continuum.  It's really based on the roast.  I think the question is a duplicate, but others can weigh in.

Comment: Wow! I'm gonna claim the guessing prize for today ;)

Comment: Rather than duplicate, shouldn't this be migrated to Coffee.SE?

Comment: @FuzzyChef Wow. There is Coffee.SE!? (But no Tea.SE! That's like Vim but not emacs? cats but not dogs? Is the  universe not supposed to be beautifully symmetric? Instead it's heavily leaning towards coffee. Ah well. Probably because of all the coders.) Please turf it to coffee.SE, yes.

Comment: Yes: https://coffee.stackexchange.com/  I'd search there first, though, it's very likely that your question has already been answered.